# How to use cobertura.ser generated by ant to be used while running maven integration test

Tags: cucumber, cobertura, integration-testing

I run integration-test with cucumber cases (say: with tag@abc in feature files) with following command and pom.xml snippet -

pom.xml snippet:

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>true</skip>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.class</include>
                </includes>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <job.host.name>server-t10</job.host.name>
                    <job.email.notification>abc@abc.com</job.email.notification>
                    <cucumber.options>--format pretty --format
                        html:target/cucumber/cucumber-html</cucumber.options>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

mvn command to run the test case:
`mvn clean integration-test -Dcucumber.options="--format pretty --format html:target/cucumber/cucumber-html1 --tags @abc" -Djob.host.name=server-t10`

Every thing works fine with cases being executed and all reports produced. The problem arises when I try to get the coverage of the test cases.

I tried all possible combinations to generate a cobertura coverage report with cobertura-maven-plugin and version2.5.2 (without using ant instrumnet/report), but it just does not create any report, nor any .ser file or anything. Only logs say that - No files to instrument and does nothing.

Losing the battle, I finally downloaded cobertura (1.9.4.1) and created custom cobertura.xml. And when I run the following ant commands for ex -

`ant -f cobertura.xml instrument
mvn clean integration-test -Dcucumber.options="--format pretty --format html:target/cucumber/cucumber-html1 --tags @abc" -Djob.host.name=server-t10 
ant -f cobertura.xml report`

Luckily though, it creates all the reports/.ser file etc. However, after running all of it, it shows as zero coverage in the final coverage report for all used classes. That could be because (as I think) the mvn command did not use/manipulate the cobertura.ser created by ant instrument.

So, please help me out in this, that what and where I put something in my pom.xml so that when I run the mvn command, it uses the instrumented file (output generated by ant insturment command) and update it. so that i can use that file for my report generation using ant report. I tried putting all possible entries in pom.xml. but it did not help.

Note: I am looking for this particular solution because all my efforts have gone wastedtrying to make cobertura-maven-plugin work. I dont' know the reason, but this plugin just doesn't work for me for creating report or even running the cases.